# How to use egrep with double quotes in search string?

Tags: linux, unix, grep

I have a `sample.txt` as follows:

```sh
$ cat sample.txt
bc
it is | ERROR
first
second
third
No space left
1
2
3
4
```

I want to search both `| ERROR` and `No space left`. When I try using the below command, it is not giving the expected result:

```sh
$ egrep -w '"| ERROR"|No space left' sample.txt
No space left
```

Please help.

Comment: I guess the command you are looking for is `egrep '\| ERROR|No space left' sample.txt`. In other words, you need to escape the `|` in the expression you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are searching for fixed strings, then you could consider using `grep` with the `-F` (fixed) option (or use `fgrep`, if available). And then specify multiple patterns with `-e`. Any line matches by any pattern will be printed.

```
$ grep -F -e '| ERROR' -e 'No space left' sample.txt 
it is | ERROR
No space left
```